# BashからPHPを実行するときだけ特定の設定を変更したい

Tags: php

お世話になります。

最近BashからPHPを呼び出すことがあります。
　その際に特定の設定項目（具体的にいうと、「date.timezone」）の設定値を変更したいのですが、何か良い方法はないでしょうか。
　なお、ルート権限がないので、「php.ini」を直接編集することはできない状況です。
　何か良い方法をご存知でしたら、教えていただけると幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: php コマンドの `-d` オプションを使うのはどうでしょうか。例えば、`php -d date.timezone='America/Los_Angeles' script.php` などとします。

Comment: このphpはbash以外から実行する可能性がありますか？、スクリプト中で変更するなら次の通りです。`if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') { date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo'); }`とか、`ini_set`を利用するとか。

Comment: お世話になります。PHPを呼び出すときに「-d」をつけて「date.timezone」を変更することで解決しました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決したようで何よりです。解決した場合は自己回答を行うか参考になったコメントの人に回答をしてもらって承認してください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

お世話になります。

PHPを実行する際に、-dオプションを使って、「-d date.timezone='America/Los_Angeles'」のように指定すればよいようです。
　ありがとうございました。